# How to copy the newest file from folder C:\test and from all its sudirectories into the same structure on the disk D:

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can anybody help me?
I have spent many hours with folowing task:
How to copy the newest **file** (not files) from all subdirectories to the same structure on another drive?
I am solving it by CMD commands. All my scripts have bad result. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Josef

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
```

can get the newest file in current directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it does not resolve my task. I need to copy the newest file (not files) from all subdirectories to the same structure on another drive... Any help will be appreciated. Josef